# How do I validate a form in CodeIgniter when my View only loads with a query string?

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I've run into an issue validating my form as my View (the page where the form is) is loaded with a query string.

My view URL looks like: http://mydomain.com/insert/new?image=http://www.image.com/image.jpg

For this view to work, I need the query string as it looks up the image URL and performs an action on my page.

When I submit a form on this page that wasn't validated (validation works fine), instead of using $this->load->view('insert_new'); (where insert_new is my view page with the URL above), I construct a URL dynamically with the query strings and use the header('Location:' . $view); function. The view file has echo form_errors(); in it but, I don't see any errors. Is this because of the constructed URL and query string? To also confirm, my controller functions to view the page and handle the form are different. How do I get this to work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your flow is as follows:

1. System loads form page with GET url data (image)
2. User submits form
3. System validates form and redirects to to $view using a HTTP redirect

The problem is, that by redirecting the POSTed form data is lost, because the browser sends another GET-Request to the constructed URL - and does not re-submit the data!

So if you want to show any form errors you must do that in the same request as the validation, ie by loading a view after the validation instead of redirecting.

Comment: You got the flow right. I have to validate my form in the same function then? Thanks.